# Are 2001 series American bank notes still valid?

Tags: usa, exchange

I have $200 in $5 & $10 denominations. They are all 2001 series. I would like to exchange them for EUR. Are they still valid?

Comment: US notes never expire. However, outside the US, it may be difficult to have them accepted. See duplicate post for details.

Comment: Are you in fact asking about US banknotes?